# nginx cache stuck in "UPDATING" state

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, cache

On a decently loaded nginx/1.4.6 instance running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, sometimes the resources served are not getting expired. I always get "UPDATING" response instead of a "HIT" or a "MISS", which I would normally expect. This response with "UPDATING" header serves stale content, and is stuck there.

This had been fine for a long time; the only change that was recently implemented was that I recently configured letsencrypt-based encryption on my nginx instance.

Update: I'm also seeing logs that read like:

`ignore long locked inactive cache entry 9b4d24d307449cfe263aab0ee53676c8`

Comment: what happened when you execute `sudo nginx -t`? is everything ok?

Comment: Yes, everything fine there.

Answer (score 0):

**Update on this**: from what it appears, it was due to nginx process crashing and re-spawning. The crashing happened because I recently moved to HTTPS, and were using a rather lengthy cipher for encryption, which caused the server to get more loaded (using Letsencrypt, BTW).

**Fix applied** : I reduced the cipher text length, observed for over a week, and it went all fine after that.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What exactly did you do to solve the problem, down to exact commands or configuration artifacts? How does one "reduce the cipher text length" when using SSL certificates generated by a third party? What is the "cipher text" in question? The content being served? "Serve smaller files" cannot possibly be a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski reduce cipher text while creating the SSL certificate. Refer to the documentation for whichever service/vendor you are using for that. 

Alternatively this might also work out by increasing the memory allocated for nginx. (Haven’t tested, but just a hypothesis)